# Sorting issue in Bash Script

Tags: bash, sorting, sed, find, filenames

I have a whole file full of filenames that is outputted from the `find` command below:

```
find "$ARCHIVE" -type f -name *_[0-9][0-9] | sed 's/_[0-9][0-9]$//' > temp
```

I am now trying to sort these file names and count them to find out which one appears the most.  The problem I am having with this is whenever I execute:

```
sort -g temp
```

It prints all the sorted file names to the command line and I am unsure why.  Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sort does not sort a file in place, it takes an input and sorts it and prints it to stdout, which you can redirect to another file if you like (not to the same file though, because you'll start writing over a file you're trying to read from if you do that)

Comment: can you post a short example of `temp`? You want to count the number of times a file appears on the document, right ?

Comment: @PedroLobito I have posted a short excerpt of `temp` and yes you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need this:

```
sort temp| uniq -c | sort -nr
```

---

First we `sort temp`, then we prefix lines by the number of occurrences (`uniq -c`), next we compare according to string numerical value (`sort -n`) and the last command  reverse the result of comparisons (`sort -r`).

---

Example file:

```
/home/user/testfiles/405/prob405823
/home/user/testfiles/405/prob405823
/home/user/testfiles/527/prob527149
/home/user/testfiles/518/prob518433
```

---

Output:

```
  2 /home/user/testfiles/405/prob405823
  1 /home/user/testfiles/527/prob527149
  etc..
```

---

Resources:

[Linux / Unix Command: sort](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_sort.htm)
[uniq(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq)
[ptierno - comments to improve answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2671317/ptierno)

Comment: You can out `cat temp` out altogether and just `sort temp | uniq -c |sort -nr`

Comment: ...or `sort <temp | ...`, if for some reason one didn't want `sort` to be responsible for opening the file. Certainly more efficient, in either case, for `sort` to have a direct file handle on `temp` than for it to be reading from a pipe.

Comment: (Also, when given a direct, seekable file handle, `sort` can look at the file's size before it even starts to process content and make intelligent decisions about whether it needs to write to temporary files or can keep all content in RAM; when given only a pipeline, that information is unavailable).

Answer (score 1):

You could do everything after the find in one awk command (this one uses GNU awk 4.*):

```
find "$ARCHIVE" -type f -name *_[0-9][0-9] |
awk '
{ cnt[gensub(/_[0-9][0-9]$/,"","")]++ }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for (file in cnt) {
        print cnt, file
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Would it be straightforward to NUL-delimit names here, thus disambiguating representation of names with newlines at least on the find->awk side? (Granted, if they're then emitted from awk in ambiguous form, perhaps that doesn't buy anything useful).

Comment: Yes, you could add `-print0` to the find and then use `-v RS='\0'` in the awk command. If we also set `ORS='\0'` then awk would output them NUL-separated too if that was useful.